# OneSignal Flutter on MacOS Sonoma 14.0 & iOS 17.0 Developer Beta

Tags: flutter, onesignal, xcode15

I updated all my devices before the developer release and my project stopped running. However, I was able to solve the problem and would like to share the solution for anyone who needs it.

My environment:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 14.0 23A5257q darwin-arm64, locale ru-RU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Comment: There needs to be a question here because Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk James K. Polk I answered my own question so that other users could find my solution and apply it in their projects.

Comment: You don't have a question here. Questions end with a question mark ("?").

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I understand that. but what is more important: that I help people with my decision or that I formalize this post correctly? I think this site was created to help programmers solve difficult problems. I have just helped programmers solve a difficult problem with my post, and this is the main thing

Comment: Why does it have to be either/or? Why not just edit your "question" to turn it into a real question? Neither your title nor your question body give a hint as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install `onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.0-beta2` in pubspec.yaml
2. Change ios/Podfile:

   ```
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
     end
     installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
       project.targets.each do |target|
           target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
           end
       end
     end
   end

   target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
     use_frameworks!
     pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '5.0.0-beta-04'
   end
   ```
3. Update ios/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/NotificationService.swift (Replace all OneSignal with OneSignalExtension) (I found this here: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases/tag/3.11.0-beta-01):

   ```
   import UserNotifications

   import OneSignalExtension // Update here

   class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

       var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
       var receivedRequest: UNNotificationRequest!
       var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

       override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
           self.receivedRequest = request
           self.contentHandler = contentHandler
           self.bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

           if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
               //If your SDK version is < 3.5.0 uncomment and use this code:
               /*
               OneSignal.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: self.bestAttemptContent)
               contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
               */

               /* DEBUGGING: Uncomment the 2 lines below to check this extension is excuting
                             Note, this extension only runs when mutable-content is set
                             Setting an attachment or action buttons automatically adds this */
               //OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)
               //bestAttemptContent.body = "[Modified] " + bestAttemptContent.body
               // Update here
               OneSignalExtension.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: self.contentHandler)
           }
       }

       override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
           // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
           // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
           if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
               // Update here
               OneSignalExtension.serviceExtensionTimeWillExpireRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: self.bestAttemptContent) 
               contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
           }
       }

   }
   ```
4. change the order here to the same as mine
   [image]
5. I changed the ios deployment target everywhere to 14 (but I don't know for sure if this is necessary)

Comment: Are you able to run Flutter from command line tools or VSCode (not Xcode) with this? Related issue on GH Flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128531

Comment: @abegehr I always run via VS Code. I am currently using Mac OS 13.4.1 and iOS 17.0 Beta, which does not allow me to run my application on a real device due to the lack of iOSDeviceSupport for version 17.0. I am waiting for the necessary files here https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport 

I don't run my Flutter projects via xCode from the update to iOS 17 as this is not possible for me at the moment

I hope I understood the essence of the question correctly and gave at least some useful information for you